# Phonegap 3.4.0 IOS Splash screen showing default

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I am using Phonegap 3.4.0 for my IOS Project, Here i Replaced Default Splash screen from my Project to set my own Splash screen. But When app is launching old Splash screen showng.

Any idea to show my splash screen.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This bit is really ennoying with phonegap... I had the same problem. Have you replace the images under Project/Resources/splash ?

Comment: yes clem, i have replace splash...

Comment: Can't remember exactly how I did unfortunately. I have set splashscreen on my Xcode project, I have the phonegap splash screen plugin, remove everywhere splash.png - If you have done all of these I can look further in my project to give you a better answer..

Answer (score 1):

See the instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html). The basic steps are:

1. Add the feature tag to config.xml:

   `<feature name="SplashScreen">
       <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
   </feature>`
2. Copy the splash screen images to Resources/splash.
3. Call `navigator.splashscreen.show()` *after* the deviceready event fires.

If you use build.phonegap.com to build your app, you may need to specify the path to your splash screen in config.xml:
`<gap:splash src="splash.png" />`